# How to map a c# object to a soap message

Tags: c#, soap, xsd, mapping

I just wandering if I can generate a SOAP message from a object. The class of the object was generated from an xml schema .xsd file by xsd.exe.

The problem is that I want to avoid to use soap attribute to markup the object field to soap element mapping.

If this is not the smart way, please shed some light how can I mapping from an xsd to c# classes and from the corresponding objects to soap messages.

Thank you!

Best,
Bob

Comment: If you want to avoid putting the attributes in the object, you can add them to an interface that you inherit.  If you need specific control on what/how you want to serial your object you'll need to put the attributes somewhere.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the SOAP Message? Send it to a web service? Then simply add a service reference and call the service directly.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to serialize the object into SOAP format then use the SoapFormatter Class.  Try these helpful links:

[MSDN - SoapFormatter Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.soap.soapformatter.aspx)

[The Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Custom_Serialization_II.aspx)

[C# Corner](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sudhi.pro/dotnetserialization05162008100741AM/dotnetserialization.aspx)